# python - if a hint has already been given go to other random hint that hasn't been used

Tags: python

Im making this game that you guess the number, and it gives you hints to what that number is. I made this for the hint system.

```
if str(userinp) == ('hint'):
      g = randint(1,3)
      if g == 1 and g1 == True:
        print('The number',(hint_1),'than 50')
        g1 = False
      elif g == 2 and g2 == True:
        print('The number',(hint_2))
        g2 = False
      elif g == 3 and g3 == True:
        print('the number',(hint_3))
      elif g == 4 and g4 == True:
        print('WIP')
```

How would I make it so if there was a duplicate hint was chosen with `g = randint(1,3)`, it would go to another unused hint?

Thanks :) .

Comment: I think you may need to expand on your code; for instance, where is `g1` defined? Where is `hint_1` defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is in using separate variables for your hints. Put them in a list instead, so you can use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
# at the start
hints = [
    "The number {} than 50".format(hint_1)
    "The number {}".format(hint_2)
    "The number {}".format(hint_3)
]
random.shuffle(hints)

# in the game loop
if userinp == 'hint':
    if not hints:
        print("Sorry, you are out of hints")
    else:
        hint = hints.pop()  # take **one** of the randomised hints
        print(hint)
```

`random.shuffle()` puts the `hints` list in random order, and repeated `hints.pop()` calls will pick the next available hint, in random order.

Note that now there is no need to keep separate hint flags anymore either, when the `hints` list is empty, the user is out of hints.

As a side note: there is no point in using `== True` in boolean tests. `if` already tests for boolean truth, adding `== True` is redundant (and when you *must* test for a boolean object only you'd use `is True` as `True` and `False` are singletons).

Answer (score 2):

You could put the hints in a list and then select a random entry in the list and then remove it from the list.

```
hints = ["Something warm", "Fuzzy", "Meows"]
if str(userinput) == "hint":
    hintn = randint(0,len(hints)-1) # assuming the range of randint is inclusive
    print(hints[hintn])
    del hints[hintn]
```

Or as Martijn suggested in the comments, shuffle it once and then pop from it.

```
from random import shuffle
hints = ["Something warm", "Fuzzy", "Meows"]
shuffle(hints)
#...
if str(userinput) == "hint":
    if not hints:
        print("No hints remaining")
    else:
        print(hints.pop())
```

Comment: Why pick a a new random number each time? Just shuffle **once**, at the start.